# Fresh install on new pc visual studio sql error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have just installed visual studio on a new windows 8.1 PC.  When I try to run a new MVC project I get the following error when registring in the default mvc framework:

"Your sql server installation is either corrupt or has been tampered with (unknown package id)."

This is a brand new install and I have tampered with nothing.  I saw it typically has to due with renaming your computer, but since this is a fresh install it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below mentioned options.

1. Change the name of the computer where it was originally might sort
   this error.
2. Update the SQL server to the latest version and verify if it is compatible with installed visual studio.
3. If above option fails, then re-install SQL Server.

This error occurred because it might have got installed alongside with visual studio. Better install the version that is compatible with your system.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/28/sql-server-fix-error-sqldumper-library-failed-initialization-your-installation-is-either-corrupt-or-has-been-tampered-with-please-uninstall-then-re-run-setup-to-correct-to-correct-this-problem/

Fix/Workaround/Solution:

Go to Add/Remove Program in windows Control Panel

Remove “microsoft SQL server vss writer” program

Reboot the computer.